# cron command to execute a php script periodically

Tags: php, cron, putty

I am using Ubuntu. Earlier I used to run cron jobs from GUI. 
I have created a php script and saved it on my server. 
i tried to execute cron from putty,

```
5 * * * * path/folder/sample.php // script runs for every 5 mins
```

[image]

But it doesn't work.

Am I in the right direction?

Actually, where should be the command get executed dynamically?

Comment: The first column should be `*/5`.

Comment: crontab executes shell commands. Therefore you have to do `php -f scriptname.php`

Comment: Also, comments begin with `#` instead of `//`.

Answer (score 2):

The most sure way is specify path to your interpreter. You should also change 5 to */5 (which mean run every five minutes nor than run at 5 minutes past each hour), try:

```
*/5 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

Comment: You should at least include a line about why this fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Future users will be greatly appreciative. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify absolute paths to scripts and programs in `crontab`, and you mustn't assume a working directory, change directory explicitly within your script. Whatever you specify as the command, *cron* will pass to a new bash process, so if you specify a script (opposed to binary executable) you should start the script with the [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29):

```
#!/path/to/interpreter
```